# Hiding an app from recents programmatically

Tags: android, android-activity, background, task, home-button

I want to hide my app from recents programmatically when the user press the home or the task button. The user can decide if the app is persistent in background or not, this setting come from backend so pre-login activities are not to be maintened in recents either case. I tried various solution, some works partially, but none of them work perfectly. I'll list all the methods I used.

**1st method. manual task removal:** 
removes every task and kill process

```
//remove the app from recents. TODO doesn't remove if app list button is pressed instead of home
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) application.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                if (am != null) {
                    List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = am.getAppTasks();
                    if (tasks != null && !tasks.isEmpty()) {
                        tasks.get(0).setExcludeFromRecents(true);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                //TODO API 19
            }

            //kills the process
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

This works fairly well, but not when tasks button is pressed and not for API 19 (which I'm targeting)

**2nd method:** ExitActivity:
first solution found on the web.

```
public class RemoveFromRecentsActivity extends ApplicationLayer {
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
        {
            finishAndRemoveTask();
        }
        else
        {
            finish();
        }
    }

    public static void exitApplicationAndRemoveFromRecent(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, RemoveFromRecentsActivity.class);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

that doesn't work because I'm not calling it from `onPause()`, so it gets executed after the app has gone to background; I'm sure of this because it starts the dummy activity next time I click on the icon or resume it from recents.

**3rd method:** override `startActivity()` with `excludeFromRecents="true"` in first activity (Splash)

so basically I've an activity which extends `AppCompatActivity`and all my activities extend it. I've overridden `startActivity()`:

```
@Override
    public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
        if (isUserOptIn){
            if (intent.getComponent().getShortClassName().equals(HomepageActivity.class.getName())){
                intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            }
        } 
        super.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Here I tried to set `excludeFromRecents="true"` on the splash activity, but if the user has chosen to use the feature, a new task should be created before taking the user to the homepage, but doesn't work. App gets removed from recents anyways.

**4th method:** override `startActivity()` with `excludeFromRecents="false"` in first activity (Splash)

```
@Override
        public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
            if (!isUserOptIn){

                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
            }
            super.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Here I did the opposite, Splash in maintained in recents and EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS is added to every new activity, but it doesn't work. When user has not opt-in, the app is not removed from recents. I also tried `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` thinking that the app was not being removed because the first activity had `excludeFromRecents="false"` but didn't work either.

**5th method:** override `startActivity()` with `excludeFromRecents="true"` in first activity (Splash)

```
if (! isUserOptIn){
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS );
        }
        if (intent.getComponent().getShortClassName().equals(HomepageActivity.class.getName())){
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
            }
```

Here I set `excludeFromRecents="true"` in Splash and tried create a new task when opening HomeActivity regardless of user's choice and add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS` to every activity if necessary. This way the app is always removed. Opposite result if I set `excludeFromRecents="false"`, it is always maintained.

It seems like `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );` it's not working at all.

Anyone has any idea on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Android will call `onUserLeaveHint()` if it is about to put the app in the background because the user pressed the HOME or TASK button. You can set a flag in that method. Android will next call `onPause()`, where you can check the flag and if the flag is set you can immediately call `finishAndRemoveTask()`.

You should implement this behaviuour in all activities (or in a base activity that you derive all other activities from).

NOTE: This only works on API 21 and higher

---

For API < 21 you can probably simulate `finishAndRemoveTask()` with something like this:

Instead of calling `finishAndRemoveTask()`, do this:

```
Intent clearIntent = new Intent(this, MyRootActivity.class);
clearIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                     Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                     Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
clearIntent.putExtra("exit", true);
startActivity(clearIntent);
```

At the very beginning of `onCreate()` of your root `Activity` (the one with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER), do this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.hasExtra("exit")) {
    // finish immediately
   finish();
   return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at it. But I need a way for API 19.

Comment: Hi thanks again for the edit. I just tried to implement onUserLeaveHint, but it gets called not only when the user choose to leave the app as stated in the docs, but also when a new activity is created. Since there's no way to distinguish between an actual user action and the starting of a new activity, that doesn't look like a viable way. I'm trying to understand if I can use a flag overriding startActivity and StartActivityForResult but that introduce quite a big risk in the whole app, so I'm not sure. Is there really no way to do that using the methods in the question?

Comment: Ah...that's too bad. I don't see any other way.

Comment: I've now managed to use your method. Still there are some issue:1)onUserLeaveHint it's not called when the user locks his phone. 2)on API 19 when the user press the home button or the recents button, the app immediately goes to background and it has no time to start the ending activity, so it's not removed from recents (the method works while in debug so it's a timing problem).

I've managed to go around #1 but #2 seems to have no solution.

Comment: Still not understanding why `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );` doesn't work, that should be the simplest way to do that....

Comment: There is a long-standing nasty Android bug related which occurs when you launch the app **for the first time** from the installer directly or from an IDE (like Android Studio). To make sure that you aren't seeing this bug, please install the app on the phone and DON'T start it from the installer or the IDE. Instead launch it yourself by tapping on the icon on the HOME screen. See if you still have issues.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did that already sometimes, but I'll try again asap and let you know. Thanks again

Comment: So I've tried all combination again and nothing seems to work, even launching the app from via the icon :(

Answer (score 1):

This works for API 19 and above, by using the new ActivityResultLauncher.

First of all, from your main or root activity, define an activity result launcher like below;

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startMyActivityForResult = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                //Close and remove the app from recent
                finishAndRemoveTask();
            }
        });
```

then start your new activity using the ActivityResultLauncher as below;

```
Intent newActivityIntent = new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class);
startMyActivityForResult.launch(newActivityIntent);
```

Then when leaving your new activity back to main and you wish to close the app and remove from recent, then finish the activity with Activity.RESULT_OK as below;

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent1);
finishAndRemoveTask();
```

This will automatically close and remove your app from recent.